# Render a raw string with Jinja

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a string that I want to treat as a Jinja template.  I tried returning the string, but it gets sent as is, Jinja doesn't render it.  I do not want to make a template file to render it with `render_template`.  How can I render the string with Jinja?

```
@app.route('/results')
def results():
    template = '''<div class="results">
        {% for option in options() %}
            <p>{{ option }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    '''
    return template
```

Comment: What "templating function" are you expecting to "kick in" here? You return a raw string, so that's what is sent to the client.

Comment: maybe i should change my question to,  "how to render a raw string as html"?

Comment: Still don't understand what you're asking. What are you seeing on the browser, and how does this differ from what you're expecting to see?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for [`render_template_string`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.render_template_string).

> `flask.render_template_string(source, **context)`
>
> Renders a template from the given template source string with the given context.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - source – the sourcecode of the template to be rendered
> - context – the variables that should be available in the context of the template.

```
from flask import render_template_string
```

Call it on your HTML string to render it, and return the result.

```
return render_template_string(template)
```